# Why didn't we define $\ln(-1)=0$?

Tags: functions, complex-numbers, logarithms

We know that $\ln(a\cdot b)=\ln(a)+\ln(b)$.

So, $\ln{1}=\ln(-1\cdot-1)=\ln(-1)+\ln(-1)\implies\ln(-1)=0$.

It appears that this formula doesn't give the right answer for $\ln(-1)$. So, what exactly is the product formula for negative logarithms?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm

Answer (score 1):

For negative $\ln$, we have: $$\ln(-x)=\ln(x)+i\pi$$
So, $$\ln(-1)=\ln(1)+i\pi=\boxed{i\pi}$$

Comment: I think what he wanted to know is why his way didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Via complex numbers and Euler's formula
$$e^{i \pi} = -1$$
Taking (complex) logs
$$i \pi = \ln(-1)$$
Seems a reasonable result.

Also one could say
$$i \pi (2k +1) = \ln(-1)$$
For some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

It really depends on what branch is chosen to evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's consider the definition of logarithm, as usually taught in high school. We only work here in the domain of the real numbers, as we can extend the logarithm to complex numbers, but things get tricky there.

$$y = \ln x \iff e^y = x$$

Since $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}: e^y > 0$, there is no real $y$ such that $y = \ln(-1)$. Therefore, we chose to not define the logarithmic functions for negative values.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to consider is "What is the definition of $\ln(x).$?" So you take a trip down inverse lane and you find that $\ln(x)$ is the unique function with the following compositions:
$$e^{\ln(x)}=x,\text{ and }\ln(e^x)=x.$$

So, we didn't define $\ln(x)$ arbitrarily. We cooked it up as the inverse of $e^x.$ Once we had a definition of $\ln(x),$ there was a bit of time before complex numbers came about as a serious study, all occurring circa 1650.

It wasn't until Euler demonstrated that

$$e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta +i\sin\theta.$$

Which has had nothing short of a monumental affect on modern mathematics, not mentioning the wealth of work that Euler produced.

So to answer your question:

> So, what exactly is the product formula for negative logarithms?

Well, the product formula *is* as you have written it.

$$\ln(ab)=\ln(a) + \ln(b),\textit{ (pause) }\text{ for all } x\in\Bbb{R},~ x>0. $$

Now, since $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ are periodic functions, then you get into a mess trying to define $\ln(-1),$ or $\ln(-\text{anything})$ for that matter. @Bacon has provided a suitable answer to how to talk about these, due to the periodicity issues.

So, back to some history. Logarithm comes from the Greek *logos* and *arithmos,* which means "reckoning number." Reckoning means establish by counting or calculation, so you can think of *logarithm* as the **process of computation number**, just don't forget *what you're trying to compute,* and that thing is an exponent of $e.$

Back to what $\ln(-1)$ should be. So, it has been pointed out that $\ln(-1)=i\pi,$ at least in principal (it's a pun!). This can be arrived at formally, or even intuitively once you know that $e^{i\pi}=-1,$ since you're looking for a suitable exponent of $e.$

Now, the rules end up working here, since $$e^{i\pi}e^{i\pi}=-1(-1)=1=\cos(2\pi)+i\sin(2\pi).$$
So we see that $e^{2\pi i}=1,$ but since $2\pi = 0 +2\pi,$ and since sine and cosine are both $2\pi$ periodic, then $e^{2\pi i }=e^{0i}=e^0=1,$ and so you're in that $\ln(-1)+\ln(-1)=0 +\textit{some extra stuff},$  and this is where you need to see @EricLee's answer.

Answer (score 1):

In real analysis, of course, $\ln(-1)$ is undefined and hence we can't say that anything is equal to $\ln(-1)+\ln(-1).$
So the question only makes sense in complex analysis.

The complex function $z\to e^z,$ unlike its real counterpart, is many-to-one.
Specifically,
$e^{z+i2\pi k} = e^z$ for any integer $k.$
So there is no inverse of this function in the same neat sense that the real exponential function has an inverse.

You could say that the complex logarithm is a *multifunction*
that takes any input value $z$ to the set of numbers
$\ln z$ such that $e^{z'} = z$ iff $z'\in \ln z.$
If $z'$ is some arbitrary member
of the set $\ln z,$ then $\ln z$ can be written as
$$[z'] = \{w \mid w = z' + i2\pi k, k \in \mathbb Z\} =
\{z', z'+i2\pi, z'-i2\pi,  z'+i4\pi, z'-i4\pi,\ldots \},$$

where the brackets around $z'$ indicate that $[z']$ is not a complex number but rather is an equivalence class of complex numbers that differ by integer
multiples of $i2\pi.$

If we take that approach, in order to make sense of $\ln a + \ln b$
we need a rule for adding equivalence classes.
The rule could be $[w] + [z] = [w+z].$
We can show that the result will be the same no matter which elements
are selected as the "representative" elements $w$ and $z$
of the equivalence classes $[w]$ and $[z].$
And then we can show that 
$\ln(-1) = [i\pi]$
and that

$$ \ln(-1) + \ln(-1) = [i\pi] + [i\pi] = [2i\pi] = [0] = \ln 1,$$
as desired.

Alternatively, we select one representative from every possible equivalence class $[w],$ and say that $\ln z$ is the number $w$ from that set for which
$e^w = z.$
That's essentially what the principal branch of the complex logarithm does.
But then you lose the property that $\ln(ab)=\ln a + \ln b$
for all numbers $a$ and $b.$
The example $\ln(-1)+\ln(-1)$ is especially dramatic, but consider
a number such as $w = e^{i\pi/100}.$
We might have $\ln w + \ln w = \ln(w^2),$
$\ln (w^2) + \ln w = \ln(w^3),$ $\ln (w^3) + \ln w = \ln(w^4),$
and so forth, but we cannot continue this chain of equations
unbroken all the way to $\ln (w^{199}) + \ln w = \ln(w^{200}) = \ln 1.$
At some point, we'll have a "jump" in the sequence,
something like 
$\ln (w^k) + \ln w = \ln(w^{k+1}) + i2\pi.$